# Interchanging "logical and" and "logical or" in equivalent statements

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Is the following true in propositional logic? If so, is it a law/theorem and does it have a name? How could I make the statement more precise? If it's not true, can I change the conditions so that I can get a meaningful result?

If $P\Leftrightarrow Q$ is true for all "singletons" $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$, where:

1. $P,Q$ are propositions about $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$,
2. The only logical connectives used in $P,Q$ are $\wedge$(and) and $\vee$(or).

For example $P$ may be something like $x_1\wedge x_2\vee x_3$.

Then it seems that $P'\Leftrightarrow Q'$ is also true, where $P',Q'$ are obtained by interchanging every $\wedge $ and $\vee$ in $P,Q$ respectively, for example, if $P$ is $x_1 \wedge x_2 \vee  x_3$ then $P'$ is $x_1 \vee  x_2 \wedge  x_3$. Here is my reasoning why $P'\Leftrightarrow Q'$ should be true.

Since $P\Leftrightarrow Q$ is true for all $x_1,x_2,...$, I can replace all the $x_1,x_2,...$ by $\neg x_1,\neg x_2,...$ to get statements $P_1,Q_1$ and I know $P_1 \Leftrightarrow Q_1$ is true, then by De Morgan's laws, $P_1$ is equivalent to $\neg P'$ and $Q_1$ is equivalent to $\neg Q'$, so $\neg P' \Leftrightarrow \neg Q'$ is true and so $P'\Leftrightarrow Q'$ is true.

Comment: This is a consequence of the [duality principle in Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Duality_principle).

Comment: Can I rewrite the condition "P<=>Q is true for all singletons" as "P<=>Q is a tautology" and delete the sentence "P,Q are propositions about x1,x2,x3,..."? Does it change the meaning?

Comment: I didn't understand. What is the form of the new statement that you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean can I replace the long hypothesis in my question:
"
If P⇔Q is true for all "singletons" x1,x2,x3,..., where:
1. P,Q are propositions about x1,x2,x3,...,
2. The only logical connectives used in P,Q are ∧(and) and ∨(or).
"
by the shorter sentence "If P⇔Q is a tautology, where the only logical connectives used in P,Q are ∧(and) and ∨(or)."?

Comment: Because "tautology" refers to a statement that is true in every interpretation, so I think claiming "P<=>Q is a tautology" should already imply that it's true for all x1,x2,...